# Option select get value without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to sort my page content with select option, but how can I prevent reloading page?

I know that it can't be done in PHP, so I need help, how to do this in javascript or maybe in ajax.

This is my code

```
<select name="quantity">
   <option value="1"></option>
   <option value="2"></option>
</select>
```

```
 <?php
    $redirect_url = "example.com/process.php?&quantity=" . $_POST['quantity'];
    header("Location: " . $redirect_url);
?>
```

**UPDATED**
This is code what I want to sort:

```
$sql = '';

                            if(isset($_POST['search'])){
                                $search = sanitize($_POST['search']);
                                $cat = sanitize($_POST['category']);

                                if(!empty($search)){
                                    $search_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `product_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `category` LIKE '%$cat%'".$sql);

                                    while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)){
                                            echo '<div class="product"><a href="product.php?id='.$results_row['id'].'"><img style="border:1px solid black;" src="'.$results_row['img_path'].'/'.$results_row['img_name'].'" width="230px" height="230px"/></a><br><div class="br"></div><strong>'.$results_row['product_name'].'</strong><br>Cijena: '.$results_row['price'].'kn</div>';
                                        }
                                }
                            }else{

                            }
```

I sorted it like this:

```
$sql = '';

            if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
                if ($_GET['sort'] == 'year')
                {
                    $sql = " ORDER BY year";
                }
                elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'IMDBrating')
                {
                    $sql = " ORDER BY IMDBrating";
                }
                elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'userrating')
                {
                    $sql = " ORDER BY userrating";
                } 
            }

        ?>

            <th><a href="http://localhost/New folder (3)/index.php?sort=year">Year</a></th>
            <th><a href="http://localhost/New folder (3)/index.php?sort=IMDBrating">IMDB rating</a></th>
            <th><a href="http://localhost/New folder (3)/index.php?sort=userrating">user rating</a></th>
```

But I wanto to sort it with `<select><option> not with``

Comment: @Epodax it was suggested and my last code was in php

Answer (score 0):

Did't clear out what you want by `sort my page content with select option`, but for reload functionality use `jQuery ajax` for this.

**Html**

```
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
 <option value="1"></option>
 <option value="2"></option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#quantity').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "example.com/process.php", // url to request
     data: { 
      quantity: value  // send data
     },
     success : function(data){
       // populate data here
     }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**process.php**

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
echo $quantity // this value will available in success callback function
```

Comment: And how will I sort content on my page?

I put sort code into process.php but nothing happens

Comment: Did't get it by sort content on my page stuff. What you mean then?

Answer (score 0):

you can sort it when an event takes place eg:

```
 document.getElementsByName('quantity').onclick=function(){

//then put here what you want to be executed
}
```

then the whole page will not be reloaded.only that piece of code will run.